# Django local development static files 404

Tags: django

I know this question as been asked hundreds of times but no matter what I try out, I can not get it to load the static files. The strange thing is, when i run 'collectstatic' it put the admin static files in the right place. But when I browse to one of my pages, I get a 404 error on my css/js

This is for a local django project.

settings:

```
DEBUG=True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">   <head>
   <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Where did you put your `style.css` file?

Comment: When you go into your browser and left click to see the page source, when you click on the link you created does it show the style.CSS file?